# extract data from a Repository

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I don't know how to extract the data from the list and insert it into a List.
I'm developing a simple app and I've got the problem with login. The problem is that: I want to check if username and password present in the db corresponds to the data entered by the user.

This is my Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/controllo")
public String logOk(@ModelAttribute("utenteForm") UtentiModel utenti, Model model) {
    
    log.info("Controllo i dati che mi stanno arrivando dall'utente: ");
    List<String> dati= new ArrayList<String>();
    String nome;
    
    if(utenti!=null)
    {
        utenti.getPassword();
        utenti.getUsername();
        log.info(utenti.getPassword() + " " + utenti.getUsername() );
    
    
    utentiRepo.ByPassAndUsername(utenti.getPassword(), utenti.getUsername());
    
    }
    //here must be the code for take the resuts from utentiRepo.
/*if username and password==null or empty ->return "errorPage*/
    
    return "welcome";
}
```

In this controller, in debug mode, I see that users.getPassword and users.getUsername, the results correspond to those present in the database.

This is my Service class, and Interface repository was Autowired:

```
@Repository
public class UtentiImpl extends AbstractDao<UtentiModel, Integer> implements UtentiRepo {
private static final Logger log= Logger.getLogger(UtentiImpl.class.getName());
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
@Autowired
public UtentiRepo utentiRepo;

private JdbcTemplate conn;
    @Override
public List<UtentiModel> ByPassAndUsername(String password, String username) {
    CriteriaBuilder queryBuilder= em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<UtentiModel> query= queryBuilder.createQuery(UtentiModel.class);

    String toSearch= "%" + username + "%";
    
    Root<UtentiModel> rec= query.from(UtentiModel.class);
    /*Ricerca "viceversa", nome-cognome, cognome-nome*/
    Expression<String> exp= queryBuilder.concat(rec.<String>get("username"), " ");
    exp=queryBuilder.concat(exp, rec.<String>get("password"));
    
    Expression<String> exp2= queryBuilder.concat(rec.<String>get("password"), " ");
    exp2=queryBuilder.concat(exp2, rec.<String>get("username"));
    
    
    Predicate p=queryBuilder.or(queryBuilder.like(exp, toSearch), queryBuilder.like(exp2, toSearch));
    
    query.select(rec).where(p);
    
    List<UtentiModel> ut=em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    em.clear();
    
    return ut;
}
```

My question is that. How may I take data user.getUsername and user.getPassword and assign them into a list. Because after that I'd like to create the condition if(username and password!=null and !=Empty) gotTo welcomeUserPage, if they are null or empty-> gotTo error page. And I don't know how to implement this kind of logic. The method "ByPassAndUsername" doing the search if password and username that user insert into the View, if exist into DB or not. So if the user give to me the wrong password or username, in utentiRepo, in debug mode, it's all empty. If the user give to me correct username and password, so in utentiRepo I see the result. But the problem it's that I have to create some kind of controll, beacause if I don't create controll, it will go always in welcomePage, never in ErrorPage.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
    List<UtentiModel> dati;
dati = utentiRepo.ByPassAndUsername(utenti.getPassword(), utenti.getUsername());
```